# Why does rotation of iPhone cause crash when _existingView message is sent to deallocated object?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controllers: `MyParentViewController` and `MyChildViewController`.

The application starts with `MyParent`. I push the `MyChild` controller to the top of the navigation stack, so that the chain is like so:

`MyParent` > `MyChild`

I log the object ID of `MyChild` with `NSLog(@"%p", self)`:

```
2009-11-20 05:08:29.305 MyApp[2213:207] MyChildViewController instance: 0x36afc20
```

When I press the back button from `MyChild` this pops `MyChild` off the stack and returns me to `MyParent`.

When I rotate the iPhone while viewing `MyParent`, my application crashes with the following error message:

```
2009-11-20 05:08:37.671 MyApp[2213:207] *** -[MyChildViewController _existingView]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x36afc20
```

I have no `_existingView` method or instance variable in `MyChildViewController`.

If I pop `MyChild` off the stack, I think the navigation controller will release it, and I presume that it would be set to `nil`, and that any messages sent to it would be ignored. Though that's not happening here, obviously.

Does anyone have any ideas why my application crashes on rotation?

Is there a way to find out what is sending the `_existingView` message to `MyChild`?

**EDIT**

Here's the code for pushing `MyChild` on the stack:

```
MyChildViewController *_myChildViewController = [[MyChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyChildViewController" bundle:nil];
_myChildViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
_myChildViewController.title = [_xyz name];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_myChildViewController animated:YES];
UIBarButtonItem *_backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"MyChildViewBackBarButtonItemTitle", @"") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = _backButton;
[_backButton release];
[_myChildViewController release];
```

**EDIT 2**

I *think* I may have solved this. I have an `UISearchDisplayController` added to the view controller nib via Interface Builder.

Originally, I set this to `nil` when the `MyChild` controller is sent `-viewDidUnload`, thinking it is usually enough to set `IBOutlet` instances to nil in this method. But this doesn't appear to be enough for my search display controller. When I release this in `-dealloc` I don't get the crash. Is this a bug, I wonder, or expected behavior?

Comment: What does the code exactly look like when pushing the childViewController? Is the childViewController a field of the parentViewController class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to find out more about who called (found [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3410-nsmutablearray-replace-object-index-problem.html)):

> [...] Also, by the time the app is
>   terminated due to the uncaught
>   exception there is no useful
>   backtrace. If you set a breakpoint on
>   objc_exception_throw the debugger will
>   break before the exception is thrown
>   and you'll have a useful backtrace. I
>   do this with a .gdbinit file. Create a
>   file named .gdbinit and place it in
>   your home directory. This is the
>   contents of mine:
>
> - fb -[NSException raise]
> - fb -[_NSZombie release]
> - fb szone_error
> - fb objc_exception_throw
>
> It's also possible to set these kinds
>   of breakpoints in the Xcode
>   breakpoints window or in the debugger
>   console. [...]

But I assume that won't fix your problem... _existingView seems to be called by the framework when rotating the phone. The only line I can think of telling the framework to perform this on _myChildController is this one:

```
myChildViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Doesn't it work without this?

Answer (score 0):

`_existingView` is an internal variable of an UIViewController instance, defined in [UIViewController.h](http://ericasadun.com/iPhoneDocs300/_u_i_view_controller_8h-source.html)
Maybe you are retaining your `MyChildViewController` someplace in your code.

Comment: I figured as much. Do you know what is sending this message?

Comment: As far as I know, I am not actively retaining `MyChildViewController`. It is released immediately after the navigation controller takes ownership.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this too, and the solution was similar to Alex Reynolds'. I release my UISearchDisplayController on -dealloc method, but it had to be **before** the [super dealloc]. If I release it **after** super deallocation, it still crashes.